# SSRS rdlc files and SQL Server 2014 - software requirements

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc

I can't seem to find anywhere the software requirements that need to be met in order to develop .rdlc files (Reporting->Reports Application template in Visual Studio). Is the Standard version of SQL Server 2014 sufficient or do I need to ask my employer for a Visual Studio 2013 licence as well?

Thank you and best regards,

Lucian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need Visual Studio. See for example
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/creating-a-custom-report-template-in-ssrs.html

or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166841.aspx

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow too! Please, keep in mind that appreciation for an answer is best expressed with upvote, and by accepting the answer which actually, well, answered your question.